GET Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data drops the last 11000 bytes of Movesense sensor Logbook entry
I created a 224160 byte logbook entry and I try to get the content with the Showcase App:
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Mem/Logbook/Entries
ID:null Mem/Logbook/Entries OUTPUT: {"Content": {"elements": [{"Id": 1, "ModificationTimestamp": 1734712802, "Size": 224160}]}}

When I try to get the content, only 283963 base64 encoded bytes are returned. That amounts to only approximately 283963*3/4=212972 raw bytes, so some 11000 bytes are missing. It works fine with smaller logbook entries though:
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data
ID:null Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data Status:  200 OUTPUT (283963): {"Content": "U0JFTTAx...

I tried to subscribe to Logbook/byId/1/Data as suggested in https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/data_storage/ but that failed with a 404:
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type subscribe --es path Logbook/byId/1/Data
com.movesense.mds.MdsException: Failed status: 404, reason: [wb] Failed to get resource

I also tried to subscribe to Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data but that failed with a 501:
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type subscribe --es path Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data
com.movesense.mds.MdsException: Failed status: 501, reason: [wb] Operation failed

I tried to use an offset as suggested by logbook.yaml, but that seems to drop the connection between sensor and the Showcase App:
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data --es value '''{"offset":65536}'''
onReceive type: get
onReceive path: Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data
onReceive value: {"offset":65536}

I tried to read the EEPROM content directly following suggestion C in Are there a way to know how much of the EEPROM memmory that is used?, but ExtflashChunkStorage.h seems to be no longer available in the repository.
My main question is, why does GET Mem/Logbook/byId/1/Data drop the last 11000 bytes of the logbook entry? Is there a limit to the size of an entry? But I am also curious to know why SUBSCRIBE and GET with an offset don't seem to work as documented.
